# Grabbing links using xpath in php

Tags: php, xpath

i am trying to grab links from the Google search page. i am using the be below xpath to

```
//div[@id='ires']/ol[@id='rso']/li/h3/a/@href
```

grab the links. xPather evaluates it and gives the result. But when i use it with my php it doesn't show any result. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? There is nothing wrong with the cURL.

below is my code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($result);

$xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->evaluate("//div[@id='ires']/ol[@id='rso']/li/h3/a");

foreach ($elements as $element)
{
   $link  = $element->getElementsByTagName("href")->item(0)->nodeValue;

   echo $link."<br>";
}
```

Sample Html provided by Robert Pitt

```
<li class="g w0">
    <h3 class="r">
       <a href="" class="l"><em>LINK</em></a>
    </h3>
    <button class="ws" title=""></button>
    <div class="s">
        META
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML you are trying to parse?

Comment: cant you just use: `//li[@class='l']/h3/a` ? to get the hrefs ?

Comment: Im trying to parse this google result http://www.google.de/#hl=de&source=hp&q=knx&fp=243300290dd3cf5d

Comment: Doesnt Google have an API that lets you do searches?! Why go through that hassle when you can do it properly?

Comment: Gorden, they Limit to 8 results I think, this is probably the reason he parsing.

Comment: @Robert I see. I've never used it but [this article](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/04/google-search-rest-api.html) also says *you can only get up to 8 results in a single call and you can't go beyond the first 32 results*, so while it's not only 8 in total, it's still limited. Thanks.

Comment: @LiveEn the Google link that you gave requires javascript to render the results... cURL won't see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make life simpler by using the original XPath expression that you quoted:

```
//div[@id='ires']/ol[@id='rso']/li/h3/a/@href
```

Then, loop over the matching attributes like:

```
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate(...);
foreach ($hrefs as $href) {
    echo $href->value . "<br>";
}
```

Be sure to check whether any attributes were matched (`var_dump($hrefs->length)` would suffice).

Comment: nope..when i try a dump   var_dump($hrefs) outside the loop i get object(DOMNodeList)#2 (0) { } .. But when i try a var_dump($href); inside the foreach its just blank.

Comment: Are you getting any matching attributes (see my answer)?

Answer (score 0):

Theres no element called href, thats an attribute:

```
$link  = $element->getElementsByTagName("href")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

You can just use

```
$link  = $element->getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: Its weird.. Nothing is displayed.. Looks like not iterating through the foreach loop. Even when i try to echo a simple message it’s not displayed.

Comment: *(hint)* the method is called getElementsBy **TagName** not getElementsByAttributeName

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
$element->getElementsByTagName("a")
```

instead of

```
$element->getElementsByTagName("href")
```